# Career in Mathematics as an Electrical Engineer

Tags: mathematics, physics, electrical-engineering

I am a university freshman with major in Electrical Engineering. My passion is pure math(topology, group theory etc). During my first semester I noticed that our math classes are not rigorous at all, focusing on approximations and practical purposes. My goal is to work on theoretical math research or mathematical Physics. Should I stay in engineering (and follow it with a math post-graduate) or switch to math major? In other words, is it possible to be applicable for research with a masters degree in Electrical Engineering?

Comment: If I may ask, how do you know your passion is pure mathematics? Were you exposed to it in high-school — perhaps in training for math competitions?

Comment: I indeed have some awards in math competitions, but that's not the case. I study stuff my own, and I 've been esposed to some ideas from areas like differential geometry, general topology, Galois theory, representation theory etc , and I find very attractive things like Lie groups, adele rings or hermitian operators and their relationships with other theoretical topics, like quantum mechanics or general relativity.. I have a deep desire of learning all those things at the highest level.

Comment: Family is undoubtetly quite important.. I 've thought of maybe doing research in another country in my first steps after PhD, and then returning back, or whatever comes up. Who knows

Comment: You say that your passion is pure math, so sure, that's what you should pursue, although there's no reason you can't do engineering as well in a double major. Regarding rigor - this highly depends on the class! A freshman calculus course will probably not be completely rigorous.  Modern mathematical rigor does not usually come into play until upper-level classes.  Do they offer classes like real analysis, abstract algebra, topology?  If so, they are likely pretty rigorous.  If such classes are not offered, you may need to move universities at some point if you want to do pure math.

Comment: And of course, the real answer to all these questions is "talk to an academic advisor" (or a math dept. faculty member) who can give you much better advice for your specific situation.

Comment: On the one hand, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raoul_Bott ; on the other hand, keep in mind that very few people are geniuses like Bott.

Answer (score 0):

In the US it is possible to switch after undergraduate, but I'll note that the focus of an engineering degree is very different from mathematics. I'd suggest that you switch as early as possible.

One reason that first year math isn't as rigorous as it might be, and not as rigorous as it will be later, is that those courses are intended for a general audience, including engineers, who have less need for a theoretical basis in math. The same will be true of early physics courses.

Outside the US it may be harder to change after an bachelors degree.

I'd suggest staying where you are only if you want a career in EE or at the junction of EE and CS. But your interests seem to be elsewhere.

Comment: "including engineers, who have less need for a theoretical basis in math": As an engineer, I beg to disagree. Engineers _do_ need a theoretical basis in math, unfortunately universities are less and less willing to provide a decent mathematical curriculum to engineers (FWIW, when I studied engineering, the first- and second-year mathematics courses were virtually the same of those for mathematicians).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, yes, and for me. But Calculus was followed by a rigorous Analysis course. The mechanics were taught in the first courses, but the follow on courses provided the theory and insights.

Comment: Do you find possible the connection with pure math through personal reading while staying in engineering, in such a way that provides what is needed for PhD and research afterwards?

Comment: Certainly it is possible to learn. What is harder is to convince others that you have learned enough to get accepted. Having a university attest to your accomplishments makes it a bit easier. But you need to do a lot of work, just as if you were in class. Reading alone might not bring the necessary insights.